# How to get "php://input" data if I'm using Content-Type multipart/form-data

Tags: php, json, post

Is there an alternative?

I'm using [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for testing an API I'm developing.

I send a JSON with POST.
In code, `$_FILES` is fine, but `file_get_contents("php://input")` is empty.

If I don't send any files, then I can use `file_get_contents("php://input")`

PHP version: 5.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up giving a name to my JSON data, like `0=[{"q":"w"}]` and then get it with `$_POST['0']`. And the files with `$_FILES`

Here's how it looks in Advanced REST Client:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

As GhostGambler states, php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

You should not attach the JSON as a file to your request, you should add it as the request body to the post request, setting the `Content-Type` header (application/json). Then it will be available in `php://input`.

Comment: I'm not attaching a JSON file, but an image. The JSON I send is in the request body

Comment: Then there's your issue.. Once you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, `php://input` will remain empty. Instead of combining binary post data with json content, you should divide the functionality (being REST and all). Well basically you have a few options.. 1. Post image to API > return ID, post json (metadata ? ) with required ID. 2. Encode file to base64 (bigger size) and post it in the json file, decode and store. I would prefer option 1 though, bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely accessing any of the POST/FILES superglobals consumes `php://input`.

In any case, if you send a JSON payload you cannot have a multipart-formdata payload too so `$_FILES` should be empty. If you need to handle both on the same page (bad idea IMO) make sure to check the content type header or some other information outside the request's body before accessing either `$_FILES` or `php://input`

Answer (score 0):

> `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use `php://input` instead of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   `always_populate_raw_post_data`. **`php://input` is not available with
>   *enctype="multipart/form-data"*.**

http://php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php

Since HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is [marked deprecated](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), I guess you are somewhat unlucky. I do not know alternatives.

Edit: Well, you could try `php://stdin` / `STDIN`, although I do not know if this works with PHP in a webserver ... maybe just try it out.